# Trying a recursive builder for a list-like ADB

Tags: python, recursion

I'm trying to create my own list type with a new class called `TZList`,
I tried to create it with a recursive `__init__` func but it won't work,
here's the code:

```
class TZList:
    def __init__(self, *args):
        numargs = len(args)
        self.value = None
        self.next = None

        if numargs == 0:
            self.value = None
            self.next = None
        elif numargs == 1:
            self.value = args[0]
            self.next = None
        else:
                self.value = args[0]
                numargs -= 1
                args = args[1:]
                self.next = TZList(args)
```

when i try to get the data like this:

```
t = TZList(1,2,3)
print(t.value)
print(t.next.value)
print(t.next.next.value)
```

i get a weird print:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
1
(2, 3)
  File "C:\****\a3.py", line 79, in <module>
    print(t.next.next.value)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'value'
```

and i have no idea why, hope you could help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is the way you are repassing args into TZList.  You are passing it as a tuple.  Instead of `self.next = TZList(args)` do `self.next = TZList(*args)`